# SH conditional redirection

Tags: bash, redirection, sh

I want to be able to redirect some output of my script to `/dev/null` based on a command line switch.
I don't know how should I do it.

In a silly way, it would be something like this (in a too simplified way):

```
#!/bin/sh

REDIRECT=

if [ $# -ge 1 -a "$1" = "--verbose" ]; then
    echo    "Verbose mode."
    REDIRECT='1>&2 > /dev/null'
fi

echo "Things I want to see regardless of my verbose switch."

#... Other things...

# This command and others along the script should only be seen if I am in verbose mode.
ls -l $REDIRECT
```

Any clues, please?

Thanks people.

Comment: Looks like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756535/conditional-redirection-in-bash has the answer you want, more-or-less

Comment: You are right. This link gives me an answer. Sorry for not being able to find it before. Really thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tie STDOUT to another handle if you are in verbose mode, otherwise link those handles to /dev/null. Then write your script so the optional stuff points to the extra handles.

```
#!/bin/sh

exec 6>/dev/null

if [ $# -ge 1 -a "$1" = "--verbose" ]; then
echo    "Verbose mode."
exec 6>&1
fi

echo "Things I want to see regardless of my verbose switch."

#... Other things...

# This command and others along the script should only be seen if I am in verbose mode.
ls -l >&6 2>&1
```

That should get you started. I'm not sure if that is BASH specific or not. It was just a memory of long ago. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about `sh` but in `bash` (not the same!) you'll need to use `eval`:

```
$ x='> foo'
$ echo Hi $x
Hi > foo
$ eval echo Hi $x
$ cat foo
Hi
```

Comment: I don't need it to go backward. I just want to have the evaluation going asortedly on across my script without need to `ifing` or `evaling` everywhere. This script is meant to run on a constrainded embedded device where scripts go really slow. I feel it must be a trick for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe your test is backwards. You want to redirect to `/dev/null` when *not* in verbose mode:

```
if [ $# -ge 1 -a "$1" = "--verbose" ]; then
    echo    "Verbose mode."
else
    REDIRECT='2>&1 >/dev/null'
fi
```